# How to replicate marker position on map loop Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, markers

I'm using Leaflet JS to build a custom map (with custom tiles), it loops East to West. I've added a couple layers of markers and polygons (to indicate a route in the map) and each marker has pop up date within it. I want to duplicate the marker/polygon layers in the seemingly same position on the cloned map loops left and right of the original layer.

```
  var mapMinZoom = 2;
  var mapMaxZoom = 6;

  var tiles = L.tileLayer('../bigger_map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    unloadInvisibleTiles : false,
    reuseTiles : true,
    updateWhenIdle : false,
    continousWorld : true,
    noWrap: false          
  });

  var marker = L.marker([-110.25, 120.6875]).bindPopup("<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/114950712'>Vimeo</iframe>"),
      markerSecond = L.marker([ -85.71875, 111.8125]).bindPopup("<a href='#vid' class='fancybox-media'>  click me </a>"),
      markerThird = L.marker([ -71, 100]).bindPopup("<a href='#vid' class='fancybox-media'>  click me </a>"),
      markerFourth = L.marker([ -62.75, 82.75]).bindPopup("<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/114950712'>Vimeo</iframe>"),
      markerFifth = L.marker([ -52.5, 48]).bindPopup("<a href='#vid' class='fancybox-media'>  click me </a>"),
      markerSixth = L.marker([ -75.75, 57]).bindPopup("<a href='#vid' class='fancybox-media'>  click me </a>");

  var polygon = L.polygon([ [-110.25, 120.6875], [ -85.71875, 111.8125] ]),
      polygonSecond = L.polyline([ [-85.71875, 111.8125], [ -71, 100] ]), 
      polygonThird = L.polyline([[ -71, 100], [ -62.75, 82.75] ]),
      polygonFourth = L.polyline([[ -62.75, 82.75], [ -52.5, 48] ]),
      polygonFifth = L.polyline([ [ -52.5, 48],  [-75.75, 57] ]);   

  var americaTour = L.layerGroup([marker, markerSecond, markerThird, markerFourth, markerFifth, markerSixth]); 
  var americaPolys = L.layerGroup([ polygon, polygonSecond, polygonThird, polygonThird, polygonFourth, polygonFifth]);   

  var map = L.map('map', {
    maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
    minZoom: mapMinZoom,
    layers: [tiles, americaTour, americaPolys],
    //inertia options
    //where the map builds momentum while dragging and continues moving in the same direction for some time.
    inertiaDecelartion : 3000,
    inertiaMaxSpeed    : 1500,
    inertiaThershold   : 32,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
  });

  var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
      map.unproject([0, 14295], mapMaxZoom),
      map.unproject([15816, 0], mapMaxZoom));

  map.fitBounds(mapBounds);

 map.panTo(new L.LatLng(-110.25, 120.6875));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Have tried to google this in various ways and none of the Leaflet examples actually have this functionality.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "cloned map loop". I don't see any code in there looping anything. Do you want to cycle the map on a interval, panning to a marker, show the popup, then pan to the next, show that popup and so on?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. The nowrap: false, means that the custom map tiles, once a users reaches the edge left or right, the map repeats itself, much the same as being able to scroll around google earth over and over if you continually pan left or right. The markers however do not repeat on the other maps (i.e. the markers are only on the centre map you view when you first load the page. Though funnily enough I do also want to implement the functionality you've stated at a later point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `'worldCopyJump': true` in your map options.

> With this option enabled, the map tracks when you pan to another "copy" of the world and seamlessly jumps to the original one so that all overlays like markers and vector layers are still visible.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-worldcopyjump

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mWKc4M?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! Correct answer, would mark as helpful as well if I had the reputation.

Comment: No problem, you're always welcome. The example you gave on my previous (wrong) answer got me thinking. There was nothing in that source that did anything with copying the markers, so it must have been a Leaflet setting. Turns out to be `worldCopyJump`, that was enabled per default in Leaflet 0.4.4 (which is used in that example) but is disabled as default in the current release. Never encountered that setting. Learned something new :) Glad i could help, good luck!

Comment: But it doesn't copy the markers. they are just moving onto the first world visible on the left.